# My code is supposed to triple all values listed, but it can only take one at a time, how can I fix this?

Tags: python, loops

My code

```
def tripleAll(nums):
    for trip in [nums]:
        new = trip * 3
        print(new)
```

Then I would call the function with multiple numbers, like so.

```
tripleAll(3, 6, 7)
```

But, when I do this, it says it can only take one positional argument. How can I make it so it takes multiple positional arguments?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your function to this

```
def tripleAll(*nums):
    ...
```

`*nums` will allow you to pass arbitrary number of positional arguments to `tripleAll`. All of 'em will be stored in `nums` and you can iterate through them:

```
for trip in nums:
    ...
```

`*` is called [splat operator](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists). It unpacks the elements from an iterable to positional arguments of a function. The simple example

```
def f(*a):
    print('function received these arguments:', a)

f(1, 2, 3) # three arguments
f([1, 2, 3]) # one argument
f(*[1, 2, 3]) # unpack everything from [1, 2, 3] to function arguments
```

outputs

```
function received these arguments: (1, 2, 3)
function received these arguments: ([1, 2, 3],)
function received these arguments: (1, 2, 3)
```

Answer (score 3):

There are few things which can be readily observed.

```
def tripleAll(nums):     # Accepts only one argument
    for trip in [nums]:  # Creates a list with the number
        new = trip * 3   # Creates a local variable
        print(new)       # but does nothing, but printing

tripleAll(3, 6, 7)       # Passes three arguments
```

Apart from that. nothing is returned from `tripleAll`. You might be trying to do inplace tripling. So, its totally not clear what you are trying to do.

But, if you have a list of numbers and if you want to triple them, you can use list comprehension to create a new list with all the numbers tripled, like this

```
def tripleAll(nums):
    return [num * 3 for num in nums]

print tripleAll([1, 2, 3])
# [3, 6, 9]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are not passing a sequence of numbers as one argument, but rather several individual arguments.  Your call should instead look like:

```
tripleAll([3, 6, 7])
```